# Doing the Emscripten Tutorials - Why does int_sqrt(25) not return 5 in this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, c, webassembly, emscripten

> What are the details of your problem?

So far using Emscripten, I've converted this C code to **a.out.wasm** and **a.out.js**:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <emscripten.h>

int int_sqrt(int x) {
  return sqrt(x);
}
```

I **require**'d the output and I'm trying to test out using the **int_sqrt()** function in Node by using **cwrap()** in this code:

```
a = require('./a.out');

int_sqrt = a.onRuntimeInitialized = () => {
    return a.cwrap('int_sqrt', 'number', ['number']);

};
console.log(int_sqrt(25));
```

The output I'm getting is **[Function (anonymous)]** even though I think I'm passing in 25 to the "cwrapped" int_sqrt function.

My question is: How can I get this to let me use the **int_sqrt()** function for the rest of my code and have it give the correct output without putting all my code inside the initializing function?

---

> What did you try and what were you expecting?

I'm new to programming and I'm still trying to learn concepts so I would really appreciate it if someone could explain it to me. I think it might have to do with scope? But I'm not sure.

Following the code exactly off of the [tutorials](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code-ccall-cwrap):

```
int_sqrt = Module.cwrap('int_sqrt', 'number', ['number'])
int_sqrt(12)
int_sqrt(28)
```

would give me an error of **Aborted(Assertion failed: native function called before runtime initialization) Error**. So I edited it to use **Module.onRuntimeInitialized** on someone else's recommendation from here.

Using **int_sqrt()** inside of the scope like this seems to work and returns **5**.

```
a = require('./a.out');

a.onRuntimeInitialized = () => {
     int_sqrt = a.cwrap('int_sqrt', 'number', ['number']);
     console.log(int_sqrt(25));
};
```

But it doesn't let the rest of my code use **int_sqrt()** properly so I'm wondering how can I get it to.

Thank you if someone could explain it.

Comment: Unrelated side note: Your JavaScript code above is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) -- you need to declare your variables (`a`, `int_sqrt`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything in [the documentation for `onRuntimeInitialized`](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/module.html?highlight=onruntimeinitialized#Module.onRuntimeInitialized) saying that it returns what the callback it calls returns. From what you've described, apparently it doesn't.

> Using `int_sqrt()` inside of the scope like this seems to work and returns 5...But it doesn't let the rest of my code use `int_sqrt()` properly so I'm wondering how can I get it to.

Since you have to wait for the runtime to be initialized, you'll have to wait for that callback.

**Assuming** Emscripten works with JavaScript's native modules (`"type": "module"` in `package.json`, [details](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html)), you could switch to those, wrap the callback in a promise, and use `await` at the top level to wait for the promise to settle.

Here's a sketch:

```
import a from "./a.out'";

const { int_sqrt } = await new Promise((resolve) => {
    a.onRuntimeInitialized = () => {
        try {
            const int_sqrt = a.cwrap("int_sqrt", "number", ["number"]);
            resolve({ int_sqrt });
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    };
});

// ...use `int_sqrt` here...
```

If you need to do other functions, just add them to that template:

```
import a from "./a.out'";

const { int_sqrt, int_mult } = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    a.onRuntimeInitialized = () => {
        try {
            const int_sqrt = a.cwrap("int_sqrt", "number", ["number"]);
            const int_mult = a.cwrap("int_mult", "number", ["number"]);
            resolve({ int_sqrt, int_mult });
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    };
});

// ...use `int_sqrt` and `int_mult` here...
```

You could make that a module that exports the functions, which are then used by other modules; for instance, at the end of the above:

```
export { int_sqrt, int_mult };
```

Then in another module:

```
import { int_sqrt, int_mult } from "./the-module-above.js";
```